# How do I change title and name button in f.has_many ? active_admin on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I want to change Title and name button in `f.has_many`.

I use active_admin on rails

This my code:

```
f.has_many :gallery_apps  do |i|
  i.input :img,:label => "New Screen Shot"  ,:as => :file  ,:multipart => true
end
```

Now Title is showing "Gallery app" and name button is "Add New Gallery App"

How do I edit code?

Answer (score 3):

I think this may work for you

```
  f.has_many :gallery_apps, heading: "Gallery app" ,new_record: "Add New Gallery App" do |i|
        i.input :img,:label => "New Screen Shot"  ,:as => :file  ,:multipart => true
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can control the displayed model name via locales.

For example, in /config/locales/en.yml:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    models:
      gallery_app:
        one: "Screen Shot"
        other: "Screen Shots"
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the simple_form gem https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form. It is a really good way to do forms. You can change the label by adding

```
label: 'Your Label'
```

Comment: I will try from your suggest 
Thanks